# Skype Room Systems cannot join external SfB meeting when invitation is forwarded

Tags: exchange, lync, skype-for-business, exchange-2016

We run Exchange Server 2016 on-prem. The hardware in our rooms is [Lenovo Thinksmart Hub 500](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/virtual-reality-and-smart-devices/smart-office/thinksmart/Hub-500/p/11SP1TSH500). We have an issue when the room devices are sent a forwarded invite to a Skype meeting. The device doesn't recognize the meeting as an SfB meeting, so no "Join" button is displayed. The room mailbox accepts the meeting however.

When the room is invited directly by the organizer, everything works fine. Forwarding also works fine when the organizer is within our Exchange environment.

This is inconvenient because many times, a partner will send someone an SfB meeting invite, and the invitee will want to join the meeting from the room. Forwarding the invite is simpler than asking the organizer to add the room as a participant.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable pipeline tracing log in Exchange server, then re-send a meeting invite and see if there is a "join button" when the forwarding email is received by your Exchange server.

To enable pipeline tracing log:

Set-TransportService  -PipelineTracingSenderAddress  -PipelineTracingEnabled $true

Set-MailboxTransportService  -PipelineTracingSenderAddress  -PipelineTracingEnabled $true

Comment: Thanks, will try to get the Exchange team to enable this.